# How to detect if Refresh button(F5) is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           //do something 
        }
        else
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something       
    }
}
```

The point is that a post back happens if I press F5/refresh button or a button click. How will I prevent the code from doing any action if F5/refresh button is clicked?

I have checked [Detect F5 being pressed and Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908075/detect-f5-being-pressed-and-refresh) but the solution of mine will be different as I need to do this in C# code.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot detect if page has been refreshed

Comment: Btw, why do you need that? What is the initial issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: @zerkms yes you can, but its require a lot of code.

Comment: @Aristos: any details? Keep in mind that closing and opening again **is not** refreshing. So?

Comment: @zerkms I have made a version that is base on idea : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68371/Detecting-Refresh-or-Postback-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @zerkms I make a key that hold the post time, and place it as hidden parameters on page. Also on session I hold the last 100 keys. If I found the same key with the same time (on post back) on my session list, then the page is refreshed.

Comment: I you want to restrict the actions done on page then 
ref [this][1]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043303/refresh-page-repeat-database-transaction/10043398#10043398


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043303/refresh-page-repeat-database-transaction/10043398#10043398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to capture something on the client - so it **must** be client side script (as discussed in the link).

It's not a *postback* in ASP.Net terms - your page is simply being requested again (GET). You cannot stop this - its just like going to some other page on your web site and clicking back through some navigation.

If you are saying you want to prevent some type of server side code you have from being run (more than x times) then you can think about sessions or cookies and read them in before you run whatever process. A simplistic sample:

- visit page 1 - set session or cookie that identifies page 1 process was run
- visit page 2 - set session or cookie that identifies page 2 process was run
- return to page 1 - check for existence of session or cookie variable, and if exists, don't run page 1 process.

Another option, if viable is to use ASP.Net caching.

Comment: Well, if the user has already pressed the Submit button once (causing a postback), and then does an F5 after that, the server will think this is another postback. I think that's the problem the OP wants to solve.

Comment: please ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043303/refresh-page-repeat-database-transaction/10043398#10043398

Comment: @MrLister - Same story, it can either be GET or POST - I was being more specific about the term *postback* in ASP.Net (this wasn't clear in the OP's post). See Sunil Chavan's link for inspiration.