# Simple way to detect page refresh/F5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, refresh

I have wasted lot of time in searching and finding the simplest way to detect a page `refresh` and when the user press `F5 button` on his browser.

I have seen most of the samples provided on net but none of them could satisfy my needs.

I will explain in a simple step way to understand my issue:

1. **I am trying to use `sessions` and loading some images and storing them to folder.**
2. **Next I have a button to process some operations on images.(Here I have a postback where I am trying to detect postback and savng them to the same folder.)**
3. **Now here comes my issue now whenever user tried to `refresh` his page `manually` or by clicking `F5` buton on his browser I need to load all the images again from the folder.**

So I need the simplest solution to detect this.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Here is my code:

```
 If Page.IsPostBack Then
 //Here I am checking if the session is there or not.If it is already there I am adding images.
 Else
//Here I am creating a new session and adding images.
```

Comment: See [similar/same SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10135617/304683)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you could check if the images are in the session. If they are, then you know it was a refresh and you can avoid loading the images again.

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
    //Here I am checking if the session is there or not.If it is already there I am adding images.
Else If Session("Images") <> null
    //Here I am creating a new session and adding images.
```

Excuse my VB, I'm not used to it.

Comment: @ivowiblo-I think that will be a postback.I have added my code how I did that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

1. If this is not a postback
2. Check custom session exists?
3. If it exists
4. This is page refresh instead of first visit and not postback either.

Comment: @Braveyard-I will try and let you know.